# RequireJs Angular execution order of dependencies

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I recently converted my project from bootstrapping angular through the ng-app default method to using RequireJs and doing so manually.  Everything works fine most of the time, but some percentage of the time I get errors saying my controllers and services of the login page are undefined, so the controller doesn't properly load and values aren't bound.

I believe the problem stems from the order of execution of dependencies.  First, here are the errors:

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=NavController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=UsersServiceProvider%20%3C-%20UsersService%20%3C-%20LoginController

So far I am only seeing this problem in Chrome, and when I have the javascript console open everything seems to work.  I have inserted a few console.log() statements to get some visibility into the order of activity within these scripts.  For three files, routeConfig.js, nav.js and usersService.js I have a console.log on the first line within the define function and another one on the first line of the angular definition function:

**routeConfig.js:**

```
define(['angularAMD',
        'angular-route',
        'uiBootstrap',
        'lib/angularSlideables',
        'lib/ng-infinite-scroll',
        'lib/angular-modal-service'], function (angularAMD) {

    console.log('top of routeConfig');

    var app = angular.module('svlPlatform', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularSlideables', 'infinite-scroll', 'angularModalService']).value('THROTTLE_MILLISECONDS', 750);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

        console.log('inside routeConfig');

        //  Because angularAMD is built on requireJS, the following paths to controllerUrl follow requireJs's conventions.
        //  They don't need a .js extention and they are relative to the baseUrl specified in require.config.
        $routeProvider
            .when('/login', angularAMD.route({
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controllerUrl: 'controllers/login'
            }))
            .when('/me', angularAMD.route({
                templateUrl: 'views/me.html',
                controllerUrl: 'controllers/me'
            }))   //this continues and returns app...
```

**nav.js:**

```
define(['config/routeConfig', 'services/authService', 'services/usersService', 'services/menuService'], function(app) {

    console.log('top of nav controller');

    app.controller('NavController', ['$log', '$anchorScroll', '$location', '$rootScope', 'AuthService', 'UsersService', 'MenuService',
        function ($log, $anchorScroll, $location, $rootScope, auth, users, menu) {

        console.log('inside nav controller');

            var vm = this;
            menuScope = this;

            function loadMenu() {
                menu.items().then(function(response){
                    vm.menuItems = response.data.menuItems;
                    $('body').css("background-color","#f2f2f2");
                    markMenuActive(vm.menuItems);
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('There was a problem getting the menu data.');
                });
            }   //continues...
```

**usersService.js**

```
define(['config/routeConfig', 'utils/urlBuilder', 'services/menuService'], function (app, _urlBuilder) {

    console.log('top of users service');

    var urlBuilder = _urlBuilder;
    app.factory('UsersService', ['$http', 'MenuService', function ($http, menu) {

        console.log('inside users service');

        var meCache;
        var refreshMeCache = function () {
            meCache = $http.get('/api/v1/users/me');
            menu.refreshItemsCache();
        };   //continues...
```

**Here is my requireJs config:**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'javascripts',
    paths: {
        'angular': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min',
        'angular-route': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min',
        'bootstrapJs': '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min',
        'uiBootstrap': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min',
        'angularAMD': '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.amd/0.2.0/angularAMD.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'angularAMD': ['angular'],
        'bootstrapJs': [],
        'uiBootstrap': ['angular'],
        'lib/angularSlideables': ['angular'],
        'lib/ng-infinite-scroll': ['angular'],
        'angular-route': ['angular'],
        'lib/angular-modal-service': ['angular']
    },
    deps: [
        'bootstrapJs',
        'config/routeConfig',
        'services/authService',
        'services/usersService',
        'services/menuService',
        'controllers/nav',
        'controllers/main',
        'lib/angular-modal-service',
        'config/config',
        'app'
    ]
});
```

When the login page (the first page the app loads) is loaded correctly, i see this after I open the console:

```
top of routeConfig
top of users service
top of nav controller
inside routeConfig
inside users service
inside nav controller
```

but when the page doesn't load properly, this is what i'm seeing in the console.

```
top of routeConfig
inside routeConfig
top of users service
top of nav controller
```

...then errors

I don't understand the bootstrapping process or requireJs' load process enough to figure out why this is happening and how to fix it.  Thank you to anyone who has any ideas.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is the best way to solve this problem, perhaps it is not.  I gave up trying to use require to specify any kind of load order in the require config or using any of the module definitions.  I forced it by having several of my controller and service modules return the app, and have them dependent in series rather than in parallel, this forces require to run the scripts in the order I specify.

So, rather than have nav.js and usersService.js dependent on routeConfig.js, which provides the app object for both of those components, I have the service dependent on routeConfig.js, and the nav.js module dependent on the usersService (which now returns its app object).  This method could continue to include other controllers and services which need to be loaded before bootstrapping.  I then finally call another file, app.js, which calls the angular.bootstrap() (angularAMD.bootstrap() in my case), and everything works now.